# How to Share LAN connection Through a Wirless Adapter By PC

Tags: wireless-networking

My computer is connected to a broadband connection via Ethernet. How can I share the internet connection though my wireless adapter(TP-link TL-WN723N)? I would like to connect my Android phones.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you should be able to use Internet Connection Sharing. To enable this:

1. Go to adapter settings
2. Right-click on the LAN adapter and click "Properties"
3. Go to the tab "Sharing"
4. Enable "Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection"

See [Windows Help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7).

Comment: It's Not Showing any WI-FI networks in my mobile..

Comment: Did you set up ad-hoc networking on your Windows wireless adapter? And could you add whether you are in fact using Windows?